# how to write log file while starting services using java

Tags: java, jsp

hello everyone i created a java file,in that java i written a code for starting,stoping and restarring a windows service ,in that i want to create a log file and write output of window service as a console please if any one knows give suggestion
   i used code for stoping service

```
      public static void stopService(String serviceName) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {

    String executeCmd = "cmd /c net stop \"" + serviceName + "\"";
    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
    int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

    System.out.println("processComplete: " + processComplete);

    if (processComplete == 1) {// if values equal 1 process failed
        System.out.println("Service failed");
    }

    else if (processComplete == 0) {
        System.out.println("Service Success");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use some logging API have a look at http://www.vogella.com/articles/Logging/article.html tutorial.
Or the other trivial option is to redirect the output of executing the command in some text File. Change the command

`String executeCmd = "cmd /c net stop \" + serviceName + "\"+" >> "+ fileName"`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to achieve this is Log4J. If you haven't used it before it can seem overbearing, but there are a lot of good tutorials out there to cherry pick from, should you need to. Put the LogFactory in your class definition and then pop lines like log.info.println("service starting"). The other keyword to keep an eye our for is FileAppender. (Sorry no better references, writing from my phone!)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the output of a command you can do this:

```
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    stderr = runtimeProcess.getErrorStream();
    stdout = runtimeProcess.getInputStream();


    // clean up if any output in stdout
    BufferedReader brCleanUp =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine()) != null) {
        output.append(line).append(lineSeparator);
    }
    brCleanUp.close();

     // clean up if any output in stderr
    brCleanUp =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
    StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine()) != null) {
        error.append(line).append(lineSeparator);
    }
    brCleanUp.close();
```

And now in output and error String you have the "standard output" and "standard error" of the process you executed.